# PHP + MySQL: How to know when an UPDATE query des not match the WHERE sentence?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I perform an UPDATE query I would like to be able to know if the operation:

- was successfully performed and has changed the value
- was successfully performed, but the value was the same of the one in DB
- was **not**  successfully performed

So, suppose I have only one row in DB and it has columns **id=1** and **my_value="abc"** and I perform the following queries:

```
1) UPDATE goals SET my_value = 'xyz' WHERE id = '9' (it would fail on where)
2) UPDATE goals SET my_value = 'xyz' WHERE id = '1' (it will go fine)
3) UPDATE goals SET my_value = 'abc' WHERE id = '1' (it is exactly the same as the already stored column)
```

Using `$stmt->affected_rows` I can distinguish the query **2** from the others (`$stmt->affected_rows` value would be 1), but I cannot distinguish between queries **1** and **3** (both `$stmt->affected_rows` values will be 0).

Is there a way to know that without to perform a SELECT query with the `WHERE id = '<my-id>'` statement?

Comment: One approach `UPDATE goals SET my_value = 'abc' WHERE id = '1' AND my_value != 'abc'`, or use a transaction, do a select to check value prior to update. Also maybe look at `UPDATE IGNORE`.

Comment: You could run a select first to check case 1, then run the update and as you know the row exists, `affected_rows` will return 1 for case 2 and 0 for case 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick:

```
SET @i = 0;
UPDATE goals SET my_value = 'xyz', id = id+(@i:=@i+1)-@i WHERE id = '1';
```

After this runs, `@i` will be incremented by the number of matching rows, whether the UPDATE changed the value or not.

The trick is to both add and subtract the value of `@i`, which will be a net change of 0.